How to intercept force feedback events between an application and a gamepad?
I want to be able to intercept a FF (force feedback) event (vibration/rumble in this case) that would normally go directly to the gamepad device file, to send an event to some other device while keeping the gamepad as the final receiver of the event. This is in hopes of creating a Linux-native alternative to a Windows-only tool called Intiface Game Haptics Router (NSFW use case, does basically what it says on the tin)
I have already tried unsuccessfully to create a python script using python-evdev to read the events going to the gamepad, but it so happens that UInput events don't carry the length or intensity information unless you begin uploading them to the device, and I have not been able to capture the event from the real gamepad and upload it to a virtual one with the same FF "capabilities" (I assume the application still talks directly to the gamepad, so the virtual device has nothing to receive?). This might be a lack of experience with the library, as I basically cobbled together some example scripts from the tutorial section on the documentation website
In a prior attempt at doing a similar thing to this, I stumbled upon xboxdrv, a userspace driver for Xbox gamepads. It apparently has some support to send FF events to a certain device due to some edge cases. Sadly this is not useful because this option has limited use as to what you can point it to, not allowing device files.
I have seen that I could use the kernel module usbmon and wireshark to intercept the USB communication, however I consider this a bit clunky to setup (both programmatically and manually, I would like ease of use to be considered, as I have heard even some Steam Deck users trying to use the Windows tool). I also have concerns about performance and latency, as some games can put heavy stress into a system and if the two devices are too far out of sync it can be disorienting.
For some context, I am a bit of a Linux amateur, I have been running mainly Arch Linux and derivatives for some years, mainly with KDE Plasma. As for the code mentioned earlier, I could share the snippet of code I have been trying to make work, but as I said it is cobbled together from examples so there isn't anything revolutionary in there.
I know this is a weirdly niche thing to try to do and a hard thing to accomplish, so a huge thanks in advance if you can at least enlighten me in my way. And sorry if this is not the correct forum, I am sort of new to Stack Exchange and had some trouble deciding to which one my question fit best.

(I don't know much about this but) So you see a device file, and you can see some events through evdev, just not the events you're interested in?  If you're determined, I wonder if you make a good solid attempt at trying to get it working, then write down clearly and concisely what you're trying to achieve, what you did, what you expected to happen, and what did happen - then the maintainers of relevant kernel drivers might point you in the right direction? I'm not au fait with kernel-world so I can't give you useful pointers even to find the right people though...

... but I bet they're more likely to pay attention to a simple C or maybe Rust program than python.

I can see events through evdev, but the only things that are visible on the event are type, code and value. Normally you would continue with uploading the effect to the device, so with the .begin_upload() function, you get an upload object that has all that data, magnitude/level, duration. However that is what I described as not working, you either have to fully stand between the app and device file (I haven't been successful with this), or create a second virtual device and hope the app broadcasts FF events to all devices. I will look at C and it's libraries, I just have no experience.

To be clear: I'm not saying "use C to get your work done", I'm saying "use C or Rust if you want to get an answer from a kernel developer, if you get around to asking one" (because those guys typically are not big into Python and everything in kernel-world is either C or, recently, some Rust)
